# How to add switch widget to a row in list view?

Tags: android

I have created a custom ListView by following a tutorial on Android Interview. Here's the link:
http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

I want to add a switch widget to the first row of the ListView. How can do it on only 1 row or some specific rows like 1st, 4th, 7th, 16th etc?

Comment: Create you custom adapter.

Comment: @HareshChhelana There is already a custom adapter in place. I want to add switch to only 1 row. How can I modify the layout so that it becomes possible to add switch to only 1 row?

Comment: Try put switch on you list item layout and hide/show base position in getView().

Comment: @HareshChhelana Can you please post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to listViews, the easy answer is:

1. put a switch in your basic layout.  The layout file is the xml file whose id is R.layout.mylist, in the example you linked.
2. hide the switch for every position that isn't position 0, show it otherwise. You can't rely on what the default is, because of view recycling, so you must either hide or show.

The more advanced answer is:

1. Use a Base Adapter as it has the methods getViewType and getViewTypeCount (an array adapter does not).  You would have to code the relationship between your array and the view elements, which again if you are new to listViews/adapters, might be too daunting.
2. Create two layouts (xml files), one with the switch.
3. Override getViewType and getViewTypecount.

You have two view types now, so getViewTypeCount should return 2, and getViewType should return 0 for every position that is not position 0, and return 1 for the rest.

4. In getView, inflate convertView if null with correct layout.  You can call getViewType(position) and switch on the result.

The advantage of doing it this way is the adapter will only pass the correct view type to the adapter so you don't have to hide/unhide the switch each time getView is called.  Android only makes one layout that has a switch.  Thus, it's more efficent.

Answer (score 0):

You can Send another parameter to adapter of listview and make if condetion in the adapter

if (parameter == 1)

{ Show Switch }

Comment: I can get the position of the row using getView() position argument but how can I add switch to that particular row only?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my layout to add switch widget to all rows and then I have set the visibility to "GONE" for every switch in every row except 1st one.

```
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);
    Switch mSwitch = (Switch) rowView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

    if(position != 0) {
        mSwitch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return rowView;
};
```